# Store some records in the application and some in the database?

Tags: php, mysql, web-applications

I have an application where it seems as if it would make sense to store some records hard-coded in the application code rather than an entry in the database, and be able to merge the two for a common result set when viewing the records. Are there any pitfalls to this approach?

Firstly, it would seem to make it easier to enforce that a record is never edited/deleted, other than when the application developer wants to. Second, in some scenarios such as installing a 3rd party module, the records could be read from their configuration rather than performing an insert in the db (with the related maintenance issues).

Some common examples:

```
                                       In the application        In the database
-----------------------------------    ------------------        ----------------------
customers                              (none)                    all customers
HTML templates                         default templates         user-defined templates
'control panel' interface languages    default language          additional languages
Online shop payment processors         all payment processors    (none)
```

So, I think I have three options depending on the scenario:

1. All records in the database
2. Some records in the application, some records in the database
3. All records in the application

And it seems that there are two ways to implement it:

1. All records in the database:

   - A column could be flagged as 'editable' or 'locked'
   - Negative IDs could represent locked values and positive IDs could represent editable
   - Odd IDs represent locked and even IDs represent editable...
2. Some records live in the application (as variables, arrays or objects...)

Are there any standard ways to deal with this scenario? Am I missing some really obvious solutions?

I'm using MySQL and php, if that changes your answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, anytime you're performing a database query if you want to include something that's hard-coded into the work-flow, there isn't any joining that needs to happen. You would simply the action on your hard-coded data as well as the data you pulled from the database. This is especially true if we're talking about information that is formed into an object once it is in the application. For instance, I can see this being useful if you want there to always be a dev user in the application. You could have this user hard-coded in the application and whenever you would query the database, such as when you're logging in a user, you would check your hard-coded user's values before querying the database.

For instance:

```
// You would place this on the login page
$DevUser = new User(info);
$_SESSION['DevUser'] = $DevUser;

// This would go in the user authentication logic
if($_SESSION['DevUser']->GetValue(Username) == $GivenUName && $_SESSION['DevUser']->GetValue(PassHash) == $GivenPassHash)
{
    // log in user
}
else
{
    // query for user that matches given username and password hash
}
```

This shows how there doesn't need to be any special or tricky database stuff going on. Hard-coding variables to include in your database driven workflow is extremely simple when you don't over think it.

There could be a case where you might have a lot of hard-coded variables/objects and/or you might want to execute a large block of logic on both sets of information. In this case it could be beneficial to have an array that holds the hard-coded information and then you could just add the queried information to that array before you perform any logic on it.

In the case of payment processors, I would assume that you're referring to online payments using different services such as PayPal, or a credit card, or something else. This would make the most sense as a Payment class that has a separate function for each payment method. That way you can call whichever method the client chooses. I can't think of any other way you would want to handle this. If you're maybe talking about the payment options available to your customers, that would be something hard-coded on your payment page.

Hopefully this helps. Remember, don't make it more complicated than it needs to be.

Answer (score 1):

By "in the application", do you mean these records live in the filesystem, accessible to the application?

It all depends on the app you're building. There are a few things to consider, especially when it comes to code complexity and performance. While I don't have enough info about your project to suggest specifics, here are a few pointers to keep in mind:

Having two possible repositories for everything ramps up the complexity of your code. That means readability will go down and weird errors will start cropping up that are hard to trace.  In most cases, it's in your best interest to go with the simplest solution that can possibly work. If you look at big PHP/MySQL software packages you will see that even though there are a lot of default values in the code itself, the data comes almost exclusively from the database. This is probably a reasonable policy when you can't get away with the simplest solution ever (namely storing everything in files).

The big downside of heavy database involvement is performance. You should definitely keep track of all the database calls of any typical codepath in your app. If you rely heavily on lots of queries, you have to employ a lot of caching. Track everything that happens and keep in mind what the computer has to in order to fulfill the request. It's you job to make the computer's task as easy as possible.

If you store templates in the DB, another big performance penalty will be the lack of opcode re-use and caching. Normal web hosting environments compile a PHP file once and then keep the bytecode version of it around for a while. This saves subsequent recompiles and speeds up execution substantially. But if you fill PHP template code into an eval() statement, this code will have to be recompiled by PHP every single time it's called.

Also, if you're using eval() in this fashion and you allow users to edit templates, you have to make sure those users are trusted - because they'll have access to the entire PHP environment. If you're going the other route and are using a template engine, you'll potentially have a much bigger performance problem (but not a security problem). In any case, consider caching template outputs wherever possible.

Regarding the locking mechanism: it seems you are introducing a big architectural issue here since you now have to make each repository (file and DB) understand what records are off-limits to the other one. I'd suggest you reconsider this approach entirely, but if you must, I'd strongly urge you to flag records using a separate column for it (the ID-based stuff sounds like a nightmare).

The standard way would be to keep classical DB-shaped stuff in the DB (these would be user accounts and other stuff that fits nicely into tables) and keep the configuration, all your code and template things in the filesystem.

Comment: Thanks Udo. I've edited the text so that "in the application" becomes "hard-coded" - in other words imagine instead of retrieving an array (or object) from a row in the database, we have an array (or object) written into the code. Not "default" values either - they serve to form the blueprint for an object - but an actual object with its own specific values.

Answer (score 1):

I think that keeping some fixed values hard-coded in the application may be a good way to deal with the problem. In most cases, it will even reduce load on database server, because some not all the values must be retrieved via SQL.

But there are cases when it could lead to performance issues, mainly if you have to join values coming from the database with your hard-coded values. In this case, storing all the values in database may have better performance, because all values could be optimized and processed by the database server, rather than getting all the values from SQL query and joining them manually in the code.

To deal with this case, you can store the values in database, but inserts and updates must be handled just by your maintenance or upgrade routines. If you have a bigger concern about not letting the data be modified, you can setup a maintenance routine to check if the values from the database are the same as the code from time to time. In this case, this database tables act much like a "cache" of the hard-coded values. And when you don't need to join the fixed values with the database values, you can  still get them from the code, avoiding an unnecessary SQL query (because you're sure the values are the same).